# Elasticsearch cluster resetting

Tags: elasticsearch, failover

We have a 3 node cluster as 
1st Node : master+data
2nd Node : data
3rd Node : data

We realized that the cluster is not configured correctly. So we have to reconfigure it as all the 3 nodes having master+data property for failover.

As per documentation of elastic search we can not update Master / Data node config through an API. It is set up at the initial setup time only. We can add more nodes but can't update the existing nodes configuration pertaining to Master and Data.

So we are planning to completely set it up again i.e. changing the elasticsearch.yml config files for all 3 nodes.

But the challenge is, already the data was indexed in it. Is there any way by which we can restore the indices in the newly reconfigured cluster?

I explored the SNAPSHOT / RESTORE option, but not sure if it can be used for the mentioned scenario. Because the newly reconfigured cluster can not use the same repository and snapshot for restoring, I guess.

Comment: I don't think you need to start from scratch. Just change the other two data nodes (2nd and 3rd) to also be master eligible and restart the cluster. All of them hold data, so setting the other two to be, also, master shouldn't change anything related to the existing data. But, if you can and to be completely safe, perform a snapshot before changing this. How I would do this change: shutdown the cluster `curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/_shutdown'`, add `node.master: true` to config files, then start the cluster.

Comment: @AndreiStefan Sounds perfect. Let me try the solution you suggested. Thanks!